# Document title shown wrong in Search Result SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search-results, managed-property

I am working on SharePoint 2013 Search.

I have documents with title, name and other fields with value in the document library.

In search result the title value is documents metadata title instead of the value in the  property field title.

Is there any option to show the value in the property field "Title".

The crawled property used for managed property Title is in order shown below:

1. TermTitle
2. Office:2
3. ows_BaseName
4. Title
5. MailSubject
6. Mail:5
7. People:PreferredName
8. ows_title
9. Basic:10
10. Basic:9

I even tried by moving the ows_title as the first priority. but still the title is shown from the document content mainly the heading or first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i applied the october CU and all the previous patches in their order of release.

After that i went to Central Admin >> Search service Application >> Search Schema

and searched for the "Title" Managed Property and moved the "MetadataExtractorTitle" towards the lowermost order and gave a full crawl

After that when i did a search it worked as expected.

Thanks @steve

Comment: I have no "MetadataExtractotTitle" in my "Title" Managed Property. How can I do it otherwise? (I'm using SP2010)

Answer (score 2):

The enableOptimisticTitleOverride no longer exists in SP2013. This problem has been fixed in the October CU. You can read more here in this long thread.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2b79edd-1a77-49ee-b480-cba43edee761/search-returns-incorrect-document-title-under-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2010 this problem can be fixed by setting the value of EnableOptimisticTitleOverride to 0 in the registry key
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0\Search\Global\Gathering Manager]

This does not work for SP 2013.

You can try by creating a new managed property and map TermTile and Title crawled properties.
As per [this post](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013_05_01_archive.html) doing that with OOB Title managed property has no effect.