# SharePoint Online - SharePoint Search returns with incorrect titles of the document

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, crawled-property

I believe this is a known behavior of SharePoint search as it returns the first line of a document(assumes it as Title) when a user searches, rather than the actual Title of the document. I have read multiple blogs that explains a solution to this behavior in On Premise environment SP 2013.

For reference, "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/10/30/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements/"

& "[Document title shown wrong in Search Result SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94150/document-title-shown-wrong-in-search-result-sharepoint-2013)"

I was trying to figure out, if these solutions are applicable to SharePoint Online environment. If not, is there anything else that I can give a try.

Answer (score 5):

We noticed this in our tenant. To fix this, we:

- Went into the search settings of SPO Central Administration
- Went to Manage Schema
- Search for the managed property Title
- Move MetaDataExtractor to the bottom of the list and
- Move Title to the top

Then in the site experiencing the issue, go to Site Settings and go to Search and offline availability. Initiate a reindex on the site. Wait up to 24 hours for the reindex to occur (on demand crawls are queued and executed based on load) and perform your search again.

Comment: Nice find! I wonder if this can be automated?

Comment: I have re indexed the site. I will let you know if it worked. Thanks Eric

Comment: Thank you Eric, this was indeed very helpful. As I don't know much about the other properties, do you think there might be a downfall to throwing down the MetaDataExtractor all the way down?